# How to disable checkboxes universally for all languages using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a web application with checkboxes that I want to universally disable using CSS, regardless of the language displayed on the page. I initially used the following CSS to disable checkboxes with specific aria-label attributes, but it does not work for all languages:

```
label[aria-label="Select All"] {
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

I want to disable checkboxes for all languages without considering the text content. How can I achieve this using CSS?

Here is an example of a label in French which is still visible.

```
<label class="label_label__1lyg41o0 base_componentBase__159h7ep0 label_variant_regular__1lyg41o1 checkbox_checkbox__1tqnmmh3 base_componentBase__159h7ep0" aria-label="Sélectionner tout"
```

Comment: I think we need more details of your code for this, e.g. siblings and parents of that `<label>`

Comment: @Damzaky Added parent and sibling

Comment: Wouldn't the `input[type="checkbox"]` selector work?

Comment: I have a custom element containing multiple checkboxes, with the first checkbox intended for 'Select All' functionality. So I need to disable this 'Select All' checkbox using CSS. input[type="checkbox"] is not working for me. So i tried with aria-label which wirked like a charm but only when default language is eng

Comment: can you show the code for french too? or other language

Comment: Added 2 examples for eng and fr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can use this selector `th[class*="selectAll"] > label` and just select the parent of the label which contains the "select all" text then select the label itself:

```css
th[class*="selectAll"]>label {
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
Select all checkboxes:
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="table_headerCellVariant_selectAll_cgtdxkf">
        <label aria-label="Selectionner tout"><input type="checkbox" /></label>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="table_headerCellVariant_selectAll_cgtdxkf">
        <label aria-label="Select all"><input type="checkbox" /></label>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
Other checkboxes:
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Did you find this selector in this line? table_headerCell__cgtdxke base_focusRingBase__159h7ep1 table_headerCellVariant_selectAll__cgtdxkf
It`s working. thank you

Comment: yes, anytime sir. Just a suggestion, in the future if you make any other questions, please give it more detailed codes and also try to post the real code instead of the screenshot of it, cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Instead of label use input attribute.